# What am I missing when I want to use VBA within Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a possibly boring question for you guys. I try to get VBA for Excel running on a borrowed Windows laptop but I don't succeed in doing so.

For example, a simple function like:

```
Function addtwo(a,b)
     addtwo = a + b 
End Function
```

... does not work properly. All functions return #VALUE!.

I have set the macro settings such that all macro's should be enabled.

What is going wrong? I am totally lost....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does work as a UDF (called from a formula in a cell).  And it is being evaluated, so your security settings are fine (it it wern't you would get `#NAME?` and not `#VALUE!`)

So, the function itself is returning the error.  One way this can happen is if you pass it one numeric and one string parameter.